# how to get absolute path of a selected item on listview on mouse double click

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am adding some files to the listview. I want to get absolute path of an item in a listview on mouse double click. Below is the code and xaml I am using to retrieve items and add them to listview

Code:

```
public class Documents
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

//Code to retrieve documents

        String docpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string[] docnames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(docpath);

        foreach (string docname1 in docnames)
        {                
            System.Drawing.Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(docname1);
            string docname = Regex.Match(docname1, @".*\\([^\\]+$)").Groups[1].Value;

            System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();

            int fileExtPos = docname.LastIndexOf(".");
            if (fileExtPos >= 0)
                docname = docname.Substring(0, fileExtPos);

            FileInfo fileExt;
            fileExt = new FileInfo(docname1);
            if (fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".doc" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".docx" || 
                fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".xls" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".xlsx" || 
                fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".txt" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".rtf" || 
                fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".pdf" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".dot" || 
                fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".html" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".odt" || 
                fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".odm" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".ott" || 
                fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".info" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".xml" || 
                fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".xps" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".xhtml" || 
                fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".omm" || fileExt.Extension.ToLower() == ".csv")
            {

                files.Add(new Documents()
                {
                    Name = docname,
                    Image = icon.ToImageSource()
                });
            }
        }
```

XAML:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Column="1" Header="My Documents" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,10" Width="200">
        <ListView x:Name="DocsListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Margin="5,5,5,5" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ItemsSource="{Binding docs, ElementName=MyWindow}" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="File" Width=" auto">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListView_MouseDClick" />

                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </GroupBox>
```

Comment: There is a class named Path in System.IO. You should try to look at it because many lines of your code could be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enhance your Documents class with

```
public string Path
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

In your method use the following to create your Documents instance:

```
files.Add(new Documents()
{
    Name = docname,
    Image = icon.ToImageSource(),
    Path = docname1
});
```

In the event handler `ListView_MouseDClick` you should be able to get the Documents instance and use the Path property.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FullName` property of the `FileInfo` object you use. I returns the full path of a file.

If you need the path later in your application you should extend your `Documents` class with a property to store the path of the file.